# How to query in symfony that has an array?

Tags: php, symfony

The first thing that I do is to search all the users, and I successfully show all the users. Now I'm trying to query the roles of users, but it displays an array, like the image
[image]

Do you have an idea on how to query this in symfony? or Is this allowed in symfony to query an array? I have no idea on how to do it. I try to search it to google but no result found. I'm just stuck on this query

```
$query =  $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.role = :parameter')
            ->setParameter('parameter', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **=** by **like** :

```
->where('u.role like :parameter')
->setParameter('parameter', '%ROLE_ADMIN%')
```